# Lifetimes for implementing a trait's associated type with a reference

Tags: rust, reference, traits, lifetime, associated-types

I have a trait with an associated type, but I want to implement it with a reference type, however I can't get the lifetimes right.

For example, without references, suppose I have:

```
trait DoesStuff {
    type Output;
    
    fn do_thing(&mut self, x: f64) -> Self::Output;
}

struct SummingWidget {
    sum_so_far: f64
}

impl SummingWidget {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self{
            sum_so_far: 0.0
        }
    }
}

impl DoesStuff for SummingWidget {
    type Output = f64;
    
    fn do_thing(&mut self, x: f64) -> Self::Output {
        self.sum_so_far += x;
        self.sum_so_far
    }
}
```

Then all works fine.  But suppose instead of returning the value, I just want to return a reference to the value held by the object.  The obvious attempt of just returning the reference, results in request for a lifetime on the associated type.

```
    type Output = &f64;
```

Adding a lifetime to the associated type then requires it added to the impl, and it is then unconstrained, so I try adding it to the struct, which then needs a PhantomData and I end up with:

```
struct SummingWidgetRef<'a> {
    sum_so_far: f64,
    phantom: PhantomData<&'a ()>
}

impl<'a> SummingWidgetRef<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self{
            sum_so_far: 0.0,
            phantom: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> DoesStuff for SummingWidgetRef<'a> {
    type Output = &'a f64;
    
    fn do_thing(&mut self, x: f64) -> Self::Output {
        self.sum_so_far += x;
        &self.sum_so_far
    }
}
```

But even that is no good, because the compiler complains that:

```
method was supposed to return data with lifetime `'a` but it is returning data with lifetime `'1`
```

At which point I'm stuck.  How can I tell the compiler that the return type should match the lifetime of the struct?

Comment: You want to tie the returned lifetime to the method's `&mut self` parameter.  Perhaps it will suffice to give the method the `&Self::Output` return type?  Otherwise you will need a GAT (or the hacky two-trait workaround).

Comment: Unfortunately you can't change the methods return type, as it is specified by the trait.  I own the trait, so I can modify it's code, but the trait has to work for both value and reference types

Comment: [Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e9afed2785c70ac1ddd21b516b30e4b7) is a solution using a GAT.

Comment: @eggyal  That is the answer and solution!  That needs to be written up as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original way to do this is to make the trait take `self` by value, and then implement it for references.

```rs
trait DoesStuff {
    type Output;
    
    fn do_thing(self, x: f64) -> Self::Output;
}

pub struct SummingWidget {
    sum_so_far: f64
}

impl<'a> DoesStuff for &'a mut SummingWidget {
    type Output = &'a f64;
    
    fn do_thing(self, x: f64) -> Self::Output {
        self.sum_so_far += x;
        &self.sum_so_far
    }
}
```

This works in most cases, and it's how several standard library implementations work, like [`impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a [T]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#impl-IntoIterator-for-%26%27a+%5BT%5D).

The new option is to use [generic associated types (GAT)](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/10/28/gats-stabilization.html) (from eggyal's comment).

```rs
trait DoesStuff {
    type Output<'a> where Self: 'a;
    
    fn do_thing(&mut self, x: f64) -> Self::Output<'_>;
}

pub struct SummingWidget {
    sum_so_far: f64
}

impl DoesStuff for SummingWidget {
    type Output<'a> = &'a f64;
    
    fn do_thing(&mut self, x: f64) -> Self::Output<'_> {
        self.sum_so_far += x;
        &self.sum_so_far
    }
}
```

I believe the original method is slightly more flexible than the GAT method, since you can choose for `do_thing` to take any type, whereas the GAT method must take `&mut`. But if you have something more complex than the simple function from your example, you may need to use the GAT method.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem with the old version would be if you had multiple methods in the trait, then they would all have to take the same self - with GATs, some can take &mut self while others take &self or even self.